# Bash Shell script to calculate an address in a subnet

Tags: bash, shell, loops, subnet, calculated-field

This is a difficult one to extrapolate what I need, so bear with me. Let's say we have this subnet 10.4.x.0/28 which iterates itself across multiple subnets that look the same, i.e

```
10.4.0.0/28
10.4.0.16/28
10.4.0.32/28  etc...
```

and we have a single address in these subnets that we need to extract that will always be +12 of the current subnet.  i.e

```
10.4.0.0/28  ->  10.4.0.12
10.4.0.16/28  -> 10.4.0.28
10.4.0.32/28  ->  10.4.0.44
```

How would I go about writing a shell script to loop through all of the subnets from

`10.4.0.0/28`  to `10.4.255.240` to get the single address in each subnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell what format you want exactly, but ...

```
for I in $(seq 12 16 256); do echo 10.4.{0..255}.$I; done
```

Gives 16 lines with 4096 values like this...

```
10.4.0.12 10.4.1.12 10.4.2.12 10.4.3.12 10.4.4.12 10.4.5.12 10.4.6.12 10.4.7.12 10.4.8.12 10.4.9.12 10.4.10.12 10.4.11.12 10.4.12.12 10.4.13.12 10.4.14.12 10.4.15.12 10.4.16.12 10.4.17.12 ...
10.4.0.28 10.4.1.28 10.4.2.28 10.4.3.28 10.4.4.28 10.4.5.28 10.4.6.28 10.4.7.28 10.4.8.28 10.4.9.28 10.4.10.28 10.4.11.28 10.4.12.28 10.4.13.28 10.4.14.28 10.4.15.28 10.4.16.28 10.4.17.28 ...
[...]
10.4.235.252 10.4.236.252 10.4.237.252 10.4.238.252 10.4.239.252 10.4.240.252 10.4.241.252 10.4.242.252 10.4.243.252 10.4.244.252 10.4.245.252 10.4.246.252 10.4.247.252 10.4.248.252 10.4.249.252 10.4.250.252 10.4.251.252 10.4.252.252 10.4.253.252 10.4.254.252 10.4.255.252
```

If you want to change the top-level addresses on the fly, you could make a function...

```
iterateIP(){
     for I in $(seq 12 16 256); do echo $1.{0..255}.$I; done 
}
```

And call like this:

```
iterateIP 10.4
```